# Check for Date overlapping where end date might be null

Tags: c#, datetime, overlap

I am currently trying to check for date overlapping where the end date **might** be null. With my current code, I am able display the conflict message if scenario 1 occurs. However, I am unable to display the conflict message for scenario 2. For example,

**Scenario 1**: End date not null

1/7/2018 to 1/9/2018

1/6/2018 to 1/9/2018

Result: there is conflict

**Scenario 2**: End date is null

1/7/2018 to null

1/6/2018 to 1/9/2018

Result: There is conflict

Here are my codes:

```
if ((A.StartDate < B.EndDate) && 
    (B.StartDate < A.EndDate)) {
   Console.WriteLine("Conflict");
}
```

Comment: you just need to check whether enddate is null before trying to use it. If it's null, replace it with some notional value (e.g. MaxDate or MinDate as appropriate) which will allow the comparison in the if statement to draw the correct conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `EndDate` being null is essentially "no end date", so any date is always before this.

You can make use of the null object pattern, replacing null with a suitable always matching instance (and the easiest way to do that is to use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator)).

```
var ed = A.EndDate ?? DateTime.MaxValue;

if (theDate < ed) {
  // We're in range
}
```

Comment: May I know what does "??" mean?

Comment: @Issaki https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator